# redirecting after logout with Auth0

Tags: reactjs, auth0

so I recently got the login button to work with a netlify domain and now when I try to click the logout button, I get redirected to localhost:3000 but I want it to be redirected back to the page with the login button, is there a way to do that? here are my details for the URIs:

Allowed callback URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000,https://auth0-sample-authentication.netlify.app
```

Allowed Logout URLs

```
http://localhost:3000,https://auth0-sample-authentication.netlify.app
```

Allowed Web Origins

```
http://localhost:3000,https://auth0-sample-authentication.netlify.app
```

Please tell me if I need to include more code

Thanks,

324hz
win21H2
he/him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to add returnTo. It is said in docs https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login

Comment: Where would I put a returnTo? because I saw that a bunch of times in docs but I have no clue where I would put it

Comment: Oh wait I just realized its in the docs

Comment: https://community.auth0.com/t/logout-redirect-return-to-not-working-properly/39275
Here is example

Answer (score 6):

To anyone looking at this question now you might be getting a typescript error with the above selected answer. You need to wrap the returnTo in a logoutParams object.

```
<button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } })}>
  Log Out
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer:
So it looks like all you have to do is in the button tag for the logout button you have to add this line here:

`({ returnTo: "https://324hz.dev" })`

so that the button looks something like this: (keep in mind this might not be your button layout)

```
<button onClick={() => logout({ returnTo: "example.com" })}>Log Out</button>
```

Where "example.com" is the address to the redirect.